# Free-form integration to the website

Tags: plugin-freeform

We have always utilised modules-forms to create our forms for our website. We've just downloaded Free Form to integrate with our marketing automation tool as the simple form wouldn't work how we wanted it to.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to actually embed a form within an actual page.

Modules-forms seems to be the only way to add forms to the site.

Please help

Bree

Answer (score 1):

With freeform you can install some demo templates from which you can see how it works:

https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/setup/demo-templates.html#installing-the-demo-templates

You can also render your form with: `{{ craft.freeform.form("formHandle").render() }}`

Some additional info on that and additional custom formatting can be found here: https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/overview/formatting-templates.html